# Syntax error when trying to close View tags in React Native

Tags: react-native, visual-studio

I am currently trying to code a login screen and when I wrap my text and image components in  it is giving me an error. I'm trying to change the styles of two different view components in react native. Everytime I try to run my project I get the error: "Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?"

My code is:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import { HeaderHeightContext } from 'react-navigation-stack';

export default function App() {
    return (
         <View style = {styles.container}>
            <Image source = {require('./assets/logo1.png')}
            style={styles.hiText}></Image>
            <Text style={styles.ligmaText}>Viral</Text>
         </View>
           
          <View>
            <Text style ={styles.fontText}>Forgot Password?</Text>
            <Text style ={styles.baseText}>Don't have an account? <Button title = "Register Now"></Button></Text>
            <Text style={styles.countUp}>Google</Text> 
            <Text style={styles.monkey}>or</Text>
            <Text style={styles.flexUp}>Facebook</Text>
            <Text style={styles.house}>Login</Text>
            <Image source = {require('./assets/googlelogo.png')} style={styles.lookUp}></Image>
            <Image source = {require('./assets/facebooklogo.png')} style={styles.backUp}></Image>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
          </View>

    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  baseText: {
     flex: 2,
     marginTop: 0,
     alignItems: 'stretch',
     
  },
  fontText: {
     flex: 10,
      marginTop: 50,
      textAlign: 'right',
  },
  ligmaText: {
     flex: 7,
     fontSize: 22,
  },
  hiText: {
     flex: 10,
     height: 100,
     width: 100,
  },
  countUp: {
  },
  flexUp: {
  },
  lookUp: {
     height: 50,
     width: 50
  },
  backUp: {
     height:50,
     width: 50,
  },
  monkey: {

  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, a component should always return a single child. If you must have two siblings returned, there is a "dummy" element you can wrap you code in called React Fragment. You can use it like so:

```
export default function myComponent(){
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <FirstView></FirstView>
            <SecondView></SecondView>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Or, a shortcut is to just use empty tags, this is functionally the same:

```
export default function myComponent(){
    return (
        <>
            <FirstView></FirstView>
            <SecondView></SecondView>
        </>
    );
}
```